# compute minimum value from n integers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mpi

I need to write a C function that computes the minimum value from n inputs, and inserts them in ascending order in an array. Nothing special about the inputs. All positive and < 100. The tricky part is that the results are coming from a blocking MPI_Recv(), and the output not only has to compute the current minimum from n inputs, but also needs to keep track of which values were already inserted in the result array, so that they can be considerations for future groups of n inputs.

In short, MPI master splits up the masterArray (filled with random integers) into subArrays. The slaves sort the subArrays and return it to the master. The master then has to stitch back together the sorted subArrays into one sorted finalArray(unless I can reuse the masterArray). The master gets n subArrays, depending on the number of slaves, needs to pick out, say the first time, the smallest of the n values from the n arrays, and then needs to advance the pointer to the array that was picked from, so that value won't be considered anymore. This needs to do until all the values were transferred in ascending order into the finalArray.

The way I stored the sorted subArrays, as they came in from the master's Recv was to memcpy() the temp arrays every chunkSize elements, where chunkSize = ARRAY_SIZE/(nprocs-1) into a 1D array I called, semiSortedArrays.

First thing, I am not quite sure how you define a function that accepts n values. I am having trouble keeping track of all the pointers and how to pass n parameters to a function call. I'd really appreciate some help, as I am confused.

Many thanks, Scott

Comment: TL;DR but where's your code that needs looking at?

Comment: Errr why is this related to sorting? MPI has a reduce method that can do this in one call. http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/: "*MPI_MIN – Returns the minimum element.*"

Comment: _A function that accepts n values_  int *array;  array = malloc(7); void func1(int *a); and so on.  Do you have some code that you have tried?

Comment: Oh, I doesn't compute (I'm not even sure if this should be called computing) minimal value from n inputs... It is supposed to sort minimum values from n input vectors. I guess...

Comment: Isn't this just a mergesort?

Comment: It could be a mergesort, but I thougt mergesort merges just two arrays? What if I wanted to use 6 processes, thus 5 slaves?

Comment: @user3583629: Mergesort recursively splits arrays into two arrays and sorts and merges each. **n-way mergesort** splits arrays into *n* arrays and sorts and merges each. There's no conceptual difference between regular mergesort and n-way mergesort; it's just n-way mergesort with n equal to 2.

Comment: I've not done recursion yet, do you have any code to share that shows a mergesort of this nature? Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 5):

> First thing, I am not quite sure how you define a function that accepts n values.

Don't try. Make a method that takes a pointer to the first element of an array of values, and an integer count to state what n is.

> I am having trouble keeping track of all the pointers

I don't doubt it. C is tricky that way.

> I'd really appreciate some help, as I am confused.

My first bit of advice is: delete this question and then ask a more focussed technical question about actual code.

> The tricky part is that the results are coming from a blocking MPI_Recv(), and the output not only has to compute the current minimum from n inputs, but also needs to keep track of which values were already inserted in the result array, so that they can be considerations for future groups of n inputs.

My second bit of advice is: before you write another line of code, *write a specification*. Try to write your specification in terms of one or more *functions*, each of which takes *values*, does not mutate those values, and produces a *result* depending *solely* on the values that were input. Try to make the functions small enough and clear enough that they can be understood and tested independently.

Such a function is called a *pure function*, and it is *far* easier to reason about pure functions than it is to reason about functions that modify their arguments.

Once you have that specification written then you can carefully write the code to match the specification.  *You might end up making a lot of copies of state*.  That's fine.  Once the code is *correct* and passing your extensive test suite, then you can try to figure out how to make it faster or do mutations or whatever.

In short:

- Design
- Implement
- Test
- Optimize

**in that order.**

Comment: So, to give some of my code I am struggling with, here is the function def that attempts to find the minimum, but is buggy:

int minimum(int *array, int size)
{
 int minimum, i, location=1;
 minimum = array[0];
 
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) 
    {
        if(array[i] < minimum) 
        {
           minimum = array[i];
           location = i+1;
        }
    } 
    printf("Minimum element %d is present at location %d and it's value is %d.\n", i, location-1, minimum);
    return minimum;
}

Comment: for(k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++)
   {          
    for(slave=1, index=0; slave<nprocs; slave++)
             {
                 MPI_Recv(sortedSubArray, chunkSize, MPI_INT, slave, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
     memcpy(&semiSortedArray[index], sortedSubArray, sizeof(int) * chunkSize);
     memset(sortedSubArray, 0, chunkSize);
     ...
     position = minimum(comparator, nprocs-1);
     final[slave-1] = semiSortedArray[position];

     //Push the index to the next subArray
     index += chunkSize;    
        
             }
   }

Comment: Start a new question and delete this one. Make sure the new question is specific. I can't find my bugs is not a specific question.

Comment: @user3583629: Also please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788